# Having Trouble Getting SQLite Working in my Android Application

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sql-insert, android-logcat

I am having a problem getting my SQLite working properly in this Android application that I'm developing. It appears as though the table isn't properly being created based on the LogCat messages. I feel like I've been staring at the screen too long. Can anyone here spot the problem in my code?

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // table name
    public static final String TABLE_JOKES = "jokes";

    // database field names
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY = "category";
    public static final String COLUMN_SUBCATEGORY = "subcategory";
    public static final String COLUMN_JOKE_TYPE = "jokeType";
    public static final String COLUMN_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    public static final String COLUMN_QUESTION_TEXT = "questionText";
    public static final String COLUMN_ANSWER_TEXT = "answerText";
    public static final String COLUMN_MONOLOGUE_TEXT = "monologueText";
    public static final String COLUMN_RATING_SCALE = "ratingScale";
    public static final String COLUMN_COMMENTS = "comments";
    public static final String COLUMN_JOKE_SOURCE = "jokeSource";
    public static final String COLUMN_RELEASE_STATUS = "releaseStatus";
    public static final String COLUMN_CREATED = "created";
    public static final String COLUMN_MODIFIED = "modified";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "jokes.db"; // file name
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database creation raw SQL statement
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_JOKES
            + "( " + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + COLUMN_CATEGORY + " text not null, " + COLUMN_SUBCATEGORY
            + " text not null, " + COLUMN_JOKE_TYPE + " integer not null, "
            + COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " text," + COLUMN_QUESTION_TEXT + "text,"
            + COLUMN_ANSWER_TEXT + "text," + COLUMN_MONOLOGUE_TEXT + "text,"
            + COLUMN_RATING_SCALE + "integer," + COLUMN_COMMENTS + "text,"
            + COLUMN_JOKE_SOURCE + "text," + COLUMN_RELEASE_STATUS + "integer,"
            + COLUMN_CREATED + "text," + COLUMN_MODIFIED + "text" + ");";

    // static instance to share DBHelper
    private static DBHelper dbHelper = null;
    private SQLiteDatabase db ;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param context
     * @param name
     * @param factory
     * @param version
     */
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        db = getWritableDatabase();
    }

    /**
     * This is a static method that makes sure that only one database helper
     * exists across the app's lifecycle
     * 
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static DBHelper getDBHelper(Context context) {
        if (dbHelper == null) {
            dbHelper = new DBHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return dbHelper;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper#onCreate(android.database.sqlite
     * .SQLiteDatabase)
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite
     * .SQLiteDatabase, int, int)
     */
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(DBHelper.class.getName(), "Upgrading database from version "
                + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion);
    }

    /**
     * CRUD - Update
     * 
     * @param category
     * @param subcategory
     * @param jokeType
     * @param description
     * @param questionText
     * @param answerText
     * @param monologueText
     * @param comments
     * @param jokeSource
     * @param ratingScale
     * @param releaseStatus
     * @return
     */
    public long insertNewJoke(String category, String subcategory,
            int jokeType, String description, String questionText,
            String answerText, String monologueText, String comments,
            String jokeSource, int ratingScale, int releaseStatus) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_CATEGORY, category);
        cv.put(COLUMN_SUBCATEGORY, subcategory);
        cv.put(COLUMN_JOKE_TYPE, jokeType);
        cv.put(COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, description);
        cv.put(COLUMN_QUESTION_TEXT, questionText);
        cv.put(COLUMN_ANSWER_TEXT, answerText);
        cv.put(COLUMN_MONOLOGUE_TEXT, monologueText);
        cv.put(COLUMN_COMMENTS, comments);
        cv.put(COLUMN_JOKE_SOURCE, jokeSource);
        cv.put(COLUMN_RATING_SCALE, ratingScale);
        cv.put(COLUMN_RELEASE_STATUS, releaseStatus);
        cv.put(COLUMN_CREATED, ""); // how to put date??
        cv.put(COLUMN_CREATED, "");

        long code = getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLE_JOKES, null, cv);
        return code;
    }

    /**
     * CRUD - Retrieve
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public Cursor getJokes() {
        String[] columns = { COLUMN_CATEGORY, COLUMN_SUBCATEGORY,
                COLUMN_JOKE_TYPE, COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, COLUMN_ANSWER_TEXT,
                COLUMN_MONOLOGUE_TEXT, COLUMN_RATING_SCALE, COLUMN_COMMENTS,
                COLUMN_JOKE_SOURCE, COLUMN_RELEASE_STATUS, COLUMN_CREATED,
                COLUMN_MODIFIED }; // might need the _id column
        return getWritableDatabase().query(TABLE_JOKES, columns, null, null,
                null, null, null);
    }

    /**
     * CRUD - Delete
     * 
     * @param id
     */
    public void deleteJoke(int id) {
        getWritableDatabase().delete(TABLE_JOKES, COLUMN_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
    }

}
```

So in onCreate() (in my MainActivity) I try to insert a new record into the database and then try to retrieve it into a cursor. However, it seems to be getting caught at the insert statement.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // the projection (fields from the database that we want to use)
        String from[] = { DBHelper.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION };
        // matching fields on the layout to be used with the adapter
        int to[] = { R.id.tv1 };

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMainJokes);
        dbHelper = DBHelper.getDBHelper(this);

        long code = dbHelper.insertNewJoke("Holiday", "", 2, "Joke 1 Description", "", "",
                "joke", "", "", 5, 1);

        if (code != -1)
        cursor = dbHelper.getJokes();
...
```

Here is the LogCat output:

```
11-15 15:19:08.040: I/Choreographer(1016): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-15 15:19:35.358: D/dalvikvm(1064): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 58K, 4% free 2726K/2836K, paused 42ms, total 45ms
11-15 15:19:35.368: I/dalvikvm-heap(1064): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.315MB for 635812-byte allocation
11-15 15:19:35.438: D/dalvikvm(1064): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 3344K/3460K, paused 63ms, total 63ms
11-15 15:19:35.548: E/SQLiteLog(1064): (1) table jokes has no column named releaseStatus
11-15 15:19:35.568: E/SQLiteDatabase(1064): Error inserting category=Holiday releaseStatus=1 jokeType=2 created= monologueText=joke description=Joke 1 Description subcategory= answerText= questionText= jokeSource= ratingScale=5 comments=
11-15 15:19:35.568: E/SQLiteDatabase(1064): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table jokes has no column named releaseStatus (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO jokes(category,releaseStatus,jokeType,created,monologueText,description,subcategory,answerText,questionText,jokeSource,ratingScale,comments) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
11-15 15:19:35.568: E/SQLiteDatabase(1064):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
11-15 15:19:35.568: E/SQLiteDatabase(1064):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
11-15 15:19:35.568: E/SQLiteDatabase(1064):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
11-15 15:19:35.568: E/SQLiteDatabase(1064):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
11-15 15:19:35.568: E/SQLiteDatabase(1064):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
11-15 15:19:35.568: E/SQLiteDatabase(1064):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
11-15 15:19:35.568: E/SQLiteDatabase(1064):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
11-15 15:19:35.568: E/SQLiteDatabase(1064):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
11-15 15:19:35.568: E/SQLiteDatabase(1064):     at com.teamdotgetname.android.phase1.jokeapplication.persistence.DBHelper.insertNewJoke(DBHelper.java:143)
11-15 15:19:35.568: E/SQLiteDatabase(1064):     at com.teamdotgetname.android.phase1.jokeapplication.presentation.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)
11-15 15:19:35.568: E/SQLiteDatabase(1064):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
11-15 15:19:35.568: E/SQLiteDatabase(1064):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-15 15:19:35.568: E/SQLiteDatabase(1064):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
11-15 15:19:35.568: E/SQLiteDatabase(1064):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
11-15 15:19:35.568: E/SQLiteDatabase(1064):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-15 15:19:35.568: E/SQLiteDatabase(1064):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
11-15 15:19:35.568: E/SQLiteDatabase(1064):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-15 15:19:35.568: E/SQLiteDatabase(1064):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-15 15:19:35.568: E/SQLiteDatabase(1064):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-15 15:19:35.568: E/SQLiteDatabase(1064):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-15 15:19:35.568: E/SQLiteDatabase(1064):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-15 15:19:35.568: E/SQLiteDatabase(1064):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-15 15:19:35.568: E/SQLiteDatabase(1064):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-15 15:19:35.568: E/SQLiteDatabase(1064):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-15 15:19:35.798: I/Choreographer(1064): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-15 15:19:35.868: D/gralloc_goldfish(1064): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: I suspect that the database may contain tables created from an earlier version of the code. Perhaps I need to run ensure that onUpgrade will clear out old db and table versions?

Comment: I think you are on the right track with your above comment. If that doesn't work, I would suggest using adb to shell into the emulator and use sqlite3 to verify your table indeed contains the column `releaseStatus`.

Comment: I resolved my issue. DB versioning was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a quick glance, your code looks good. The exception:

```
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table jokes has no column named releaseStatus (code 1)
```

seems erroneous because clearly you are creating the `releaseStatus` column in your create table `DATABASE_CREATE` String. I ran into a problem where I was modifying the schema of my database and the changes were not taking effect in my application because I was not incrementing the `DATABASE_VERSION`.

Your options to try which will all cause the database to get recreated are:

1. Clear the applications data via the Settings apk
2. Manually uninstall then reinstall your application. (Just running `gradle installDebug` or having Eclipse install your app isn't good enough)
3. Increment your `DATABASE_VERSION` value

Comment: Let me check your suggestions.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for your input. Updating the database version, and uninstalling/re-installing the application worked. How very frustrating that I've spent so much time on this for such a simple fix. Much appreciated, however.

Comment: @LethalLeftEye happy to help! Good luck with the rest of your project.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that you need some space in Create statement.
Starting: COLUMN_QUESTION_TEXT + "text," into COLUMN_QUESTION_TEXT + " text,".

Comment: Thanks for the input. However, this doesn't resolve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

It looks just like you don't have spaces between the column names and the column types.  Try this.

```
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_JOKES
        + "( " + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + COLUMN_CATEGORY + " text not null, " + COLUMN_SUBCATEGORY
        + " text not null, " + COLUMN_JOKE_TYPE + " integer not null, "
        + COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " text," + COLUMN_QUESTION_TEXT + " text,"
        + COLUMN_ANSWER_TEXT + " text," + COLUMN_MONOLOGUE_TEXT + " text,"
        + COLUMN_RATING_SCALE + " integer," + COLUMN_COMMENTS + " text,"
        + COLUMN_JOKE_SOURCE + " text," + COLUMN_RELEASE_STATUS + " integer,"
        + COLUMN_CREATED + " text," + COLUMN_MODIFIED + " text" + ");";
```

Comment: So I've added spaces as suggest by everyone but that still doesn't solve the problem. SQL is normally very forgiving with whitespace.

Comment: Did you use the create statement that I provided for you?  Did it give you the same error or was it different?  Several of your column names would have looked like this `releaseStatustext,` before.

Comment: I added whitespace. The issue remains.

Answer (score 1):

In DATABASE_CREATE mistake "integer," + COLUMN_COMMENTS + "text,". No sepparate space.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the issue. :/